# CSS for Select Option to be transparent background

Tags: html, css, combobox

I have a web page that have background-image in it. After that, there's a combo box for filtering some content. I want to create this select - option background being transparent. I've read many result at google to use select option at CSS, but it didn't work. I've create a fiddle in here : http://jsfiddle.net/25CQE/5 `For example` and as You can see, the option background is not transparent. So, any idea how to solve that? Or it cannot be done by CSS?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 9):

If you want to make it fully transparent, than use

```
select {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/25CQE/1/)</kbd>

---

If you are looking to have semi-transparent background color, than you can use `rgba()` where `a` stands for *alpha*

```
select {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    padding: 5px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/25CQE/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, but it just happen to the select, not the option too.. I want to change both of it (select and option being transparent)

Comment: @CrossVander than use a custom dropdown like http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: @CrossVander because transparency will only work with flat backgrounds http://jsfiddle.net/25CQE/6/

Comment: Hmm... Got it.. So it's impossible using just CSS... I will try that custom dropdown then. Thanks Mr. Alien. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
body 
{
background: #82caff;
}

select {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

}
select option{
background-color: #82caff;
}
```

```html
<select id="nname">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="peugeot">peugeot</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm using background image, your method seems only work if using only color

Comment: simple and nice, however, does not support `background-color: transparent` on `option` in chrome at time of writing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
select {background:transparent;}
```

--edit additional --

You wont be able to style the options, because these take the style from the os or browser. You could try a javascript solution for nicer form elements such as http://uniformjs.com/ - you could then use a transparent image perhaps

Comment: Sorry, but it just happen to the select, not the option too.. I want to change both of it (select and option being transparent)

Comment: Edited above. Not really possible with just CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color for select option on css file or style, the following way:

```
select option {
    background-color: transparent; 
}
```

or for the main select input

```
select {
    background-color: transparent; 
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/eadsimone/pen/ZpZOjZ)

Comment: No, it can't be transparent... take a look this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRvBOL

Comment: @CrossVander is right, if the option is transparent, the background color of the select is used. But if both are transparent, then the dropdown part will be white. I'm not sure if this is an error or works as designed. Also, I don't like it. : )

Comment: @CrossVander are right! it is Not working for chrome(Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Some forums say use   -webkit-appearance: none !important; but it does not work for me. For firefox it is working right!