# Style the background of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get rid of the white background behind the options in a dropdown menu, so far this is my code:

```
CSS:

select {
    margin: 50px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: transparent;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5%;
    height: 50%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
select > option
{
color:transparent;
}
    .blueLabel
{
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom,  #2D3C43 0%,#2D3C43 50%,#243137 50%,#243137 100%);  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "blueLabel">
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option >Kuku</option>
    <option>Yeah, why not</option>
    <option>I think is = 7</option>
</select>
<div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0s1moa4a/)

I want it to be transparent. Problem is, no matter what i do it is still white, i can't get rid of it

Comment: Do you mean white background or white border? Background is blue to me

Comment: When you open the dropdown, its background is white, thus you cannot see the text. I can put it in several colors, but no transparent

Comment: This will not work on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `size` property of the select element (along with `background: transparent`), you get this:

[image]

You can add event listeners so that the `size` property is changed only when the select box has focus.  You have to be careful with propagating events, and you need to blur the select box on click but not on focus:

```
var sel= document.querySelector('select'),
    inSelect= false,
    timer;

sel.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.size= this.options.length;
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer= setTimeout(function() {
    inSelect= true;
  },500);
});

sel.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  inSelect= false;
  this.size= 1;
});

sel.addEventListener('change', function() {
  this.blur();
});

sel.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(inSelect) {
    this.blur();
  }
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ystvo31/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it pretty close by using `background-color`:

```
select > option {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0s1moa4a/2/

If you actually want transparent option backgrounds, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719520/css-for-select-option-to-be-transparent-background) which suggests using a third-party control as a truly transparent background is impossible with pure CSS.

Comment: well, yes, but i actually i need it to be transparent as it has lineaar gradient behind. Let me update the fiddle

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my answer - you should look at a custom dropdown control. This isn't possible w/ pure CSS.

Comment: Alright, i'll have to make my own list i guess. Cheers Nate!
PS. I'm confused, should i mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: No problem, sorry it wasn't possible with pure CSS. Sure, if my answer helped you then I wouldn't mind an upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but most elements seem to go transparent with this approach:

`background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);`

Actually, that doesn't work. It appears that only opaque backgrounds can be rendered on selector option dropdown panes in CSS. That's kind of lame.

Comment: Doesn't actually work, in this case. The browser/OS imposes a specific style on this element; I'm not sure why.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at your fiddle and it works for the selector itself but not the drop down options...

Comment: Yeah. It's strange, but apparently a limitation of CSS.