# how to change background of select box to transparent includingoption items

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

How to change background of select box to transparent includingoption items
i can not change item option

[image]

Comment: I don't think that it is possible , you may check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719520/css-for-select-option-to-be-transparent-background

Comment: thank you Soumen Mukherjee that question Asked 5 years, 4 months ago
maybe something new. just wait.